# Play Framework 2.2: Form bind not working after moving a class to separate package

Tags: java, reflection, playframework

I had a class called `MyClass` under `app.models` and when I did

```
form(MyClass.class).fill(myClassObj);
```

it worked fine. But now I moved `MyClass` into another dependency library under `com.company.newpackage.models` and after the move the bind is not able to access any `public` field that does not have a getter. I tried finding any configuration or something that might help but so far, I am not able to find any.

Comment: Have you fixed your import statement after moving the class?

Comment: @shinjw Yes, I don't have any compilation issues. The issue is `fill` is not handling `public` variables without a getter.

Comment: Do you use the full package name in your template? Only the common packages (app.controllers, app.models etc)  are in the class path. For all others you have to put them in the class path or use the full name like `com.company.newpackage.models.yourclass`.

Comment: Another possibility: You can add the line `organization := "com.your-domain"` to your build.sbt. Then during building your jars will include your domain in the file name: `com.your-domain.yourapp.jar`.